# How to unset a field in 'pre findOneAndUpdate' scope in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm trying to unset 'text' field in 'pre findOneAndUpdate' scope. Those 3 different ways I used to do it didn’t work. How is it posible to remove some field in this scope?

```
const UserSchema: SmartSchema = new SmartSchema({
    id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    userId: { type: Number, required: true },
    text: String
});

UserSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function(next: HookNextFunction) {
    let query: Query = this as Query;

    query
     .update( 
       {},
       { 'text': undefined }, 
       { strict: false } 
     )
     .exec()

    // OR

    query
      .update( 
         {},
         { $unset: { 'text': undefined } }, 
         { strict: false } 
     )
     .exec()

    // OR

    delete query._update.text;

    next();
});
```

Comment: Try with: {$unset: { text: true}} or with  {$unset: { text: 1}}